# How to change the default notification daemon to xfce4-notifyd in Ubuntu with KDE Plasma Desktop Environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xfce, services, plasma

I wanted to use xfce-like notification so I tried to get rid of Plasma-like notification

I have tried renaming, deleting /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service file but it didn't work...